# How to find partial duplicate values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in which one of the columns is having 1000s of records out which most of them are duplicates. Finding duplicates are easy but in this situation, they are partial duplicates e.g

```
ID   NAME           Status
1   abc Capital     Approved
2   (abc Capital)   Terminated
3   abc capital (dupe) Null
4   abc capitalx       Null
5   BT Capital      Approved
6   XE Capital      Approved
7   xyz Finance     Approved
8   xyz Finance X   Null
9   xyz finance dupe Null
```

So from the above data, I want to retrieve duplicate names which are partially duplicate E.g

```
output: 
1   abc Capital     Approved
2   (abc Capital)   Terminated
3   abc capital (dupe) Null
4   abc capitalx       Null
5   xyz Finance     Approved
6   xyz Finance X   Null
7   xyz finance dupe Null
```

Comment: can you please paste the data in the question itself (No Images please). and also share the expected output.

Comment: Hi Tejash, I have updated the data in question

Comment: Duplication is filter out based on only `Name`coloumn??

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use `UTL_MATCH` package and one of its functions. I chose `edit_distance_similarity` for this demonstration, but you might pick another.

```
SQL> with test (id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'abc Capital'        from dual union all
  3     select 2, '(abc Capital)'      from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'abc capital (dupe)' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'abc capitalx'       from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'BT Capital'         from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'XE Capital'         from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'xyz Finance'        from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'xyz Finance X'      from dual union all
 10     select 9, 'xyz finance dupe'   from dual
 11    ),
 12  simil as
 13    (select a.id, a.name aname, b.name bname,
 14       utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.name, b.name) simil
 15     from test a cross join test b
 16    )
 17  select distinct id, aname as name
 18  from simil
 19  where aname <> bname
 20    and simil > 80
 21  order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- ------------------
         1 abc Capital
         2 (abc Capital)
         4 abc capitalx
         7 xyz Finance
         8 xyz Finance X

SQL>
```